# Can I use .LESS variables to shorten this syntax?

Tags: less

My .less file sets colors of various elements depending on page class. So for my 3 pages (about, energy, reports) I'm repeating these elements which I feel like I should be able to address only once somehow, but I can't figure it out:

```
@color_about: #54B948;
@color_energy: #C41230;
@color_reports: #FBB040;

.about {
  @color: @color_about;
  h1, .thick-bottom-border, &.thick-bottom-border { color: @color;     }
  &.button:hover, &.button:focus, &.label { background-color: @color; }
}

.energy {
  @color: @color_energy;
  h1, .thick-bottom-border, &.thick-bottom-border { color: @color;         }
  &.button:hover, &.button:focus, &.label { background-color: @color; }
}

.reports {
  @color: @color_reports;
  h1, .thick-bottom-border, &.thick-bottom-border { color: @color;     }
  &.button:hover, &.button:focus, &.label { background-color: @color; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

yes, you can use (~"") to output variables as selectors.

```
.do_color("about", #54B948);
.do_color("energy", #C41230);
.do_color("reports", #FBB040);

.do_color(@name, @color) {
  (~".@{name}") {
    h1, .thick-bottom-border, &.thick-bottom-border { color: @color;     }
    &.button:hover, &.button:focus, &.label { background-color: @color; }
  }
}
```